# override _prepare_invoice(self, cr, uid, order, lines, context=None) in sale.py

Tags: odoo, overriding

I need to override the built in method _prepare_invoice from sale.py.

but I am getting this error

```
ValueError: "'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable" while evaluating
u'action_invoice_create()'
```

I need to override the method to create a new invoice.

```
 File "/home/cybrosys/Desktop/odoo-8.0-20150624/addons/Ship/Ship.py", line 104, in _prepare_invoice
    sal_rec = self.browse(cr,uid,id,context=context)
  File "/home/cybrosys/Desktop/odoo-8.0-20150624/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cybrosys/Desktop/odoo-8.0-20150624/openerp/models.py", line 5222, in browse
    ids = _normalize_ids(arg)
  File "/home/cybrosys/Desktop/odoo-8.0-20150624/openerp/models.py", line 6090, in _normalize_ids
    return tuple(arg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Below method override the different way based on the different API Call**

**For OpenERP 7.0**

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
class sale_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    def _prepare_invoice(self, cr, uid, order, lines, context=None):
        res=super(sale_order, self)._prepare_invoice(cr, uid, order, lines, context=context)
        res.update({'delivery_note': order.partner_id.picking_warn_msg})
        return res
```

**For Odoo 8.0 or later**

If you are using the new API in Odoo then you should follow the below way

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _
class sale_order(models.Model)
   _inherit = 'sale.order'
   @api.v7
   def _prepare_invoice(self, cr, uid, order, lines, context=None):
        res=super(sale_order, self)._prepare_invoice(cr, uid, order, lines, context=context)
        res.update({'delivery_note': order.partner_id.picking_warn_msg})
        return res
```

I hope my answer may help you :)

Comment: hi, it works and the error goes to                                                                                 ValueError: "'res.partner' object has no attribute 'picking_warn_msg'" while evaluating
u'action_invoice_create()'

Comment: in which version of odoo 8.0 new API or old api

Comment: yes definitely but you check with your code in action_invoice_create() method properly

Comment: hi, my field values are only passing when the invoice type is "ON DEMAND" how can i pass the values when the invoice type is "ON DELIVERY ORDER"

Comment: let me check from my side then after I will revert it to  you

Comment: it takes inheriting the stock.move and the function _get_invoice_line_vals(self, cr, uid, move, partner, inv_type, context=None): res = super(stok_mov, self)._get_invoice_line_vals(cr, uid, move, partner, inv_type, context=context) one of my friends solved it.actually i couldn't understand how reached till stock.move from invoice type "ON DELIVERY ORDER"..and my frnd also